# Speed of MySQL SELECT query in two similar tables

Tags: mysql

I have the following two MySQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `english_british` (
  `word_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `word` text,
  `word_transcription` text,
  `line_complete` text,
  `pos` text,
  `hunspell_rules` text,
  `frequency_coca` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `to_check` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `english_british`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`word_id`);

ALTER TABLE `english_british`
  MODIFY `word_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

This table has 112,711 records and according phpMyAdmin weighs 11.7 MiB.

The second table is almost identical:

```
CREATE TABLE `english_american` (
  `word_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `word` text,
  `word_transcription_source` text,
  `word_transcription` text,
  `o_to_check` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pos` text,
  `frequency_coca` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `english_american`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`word_id`);

ALTER TABLE `english_american`
  MODIFY `word_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

This table has 32,338 records and weighs 2.5 MiB.

Now I run two similar queries:

```
SELECT word FROM english_british WHERE `word`='I\'m'
SELECT word FROM english_american WHERE `word`='I\'m'
```

The first query (for the larger table) takes only 0.0446 seconds to execute. And the second query (for the smaller table) takes 0.1197 seconds. The exact time may change a little bit, but still it's 2.5-3 times slower.

I know that you are going to tell me that I should create an index for the column "word" and for that first I need to change its type to varchar. I will do that, but first I just want to understand why it takes so long to run the same query on a smaller table?

EDIT: both queries return just one row.

EDIT 2: EXPLAIN EXTENDED for both queries are absolutely identical (except for the number of rows).

EDIT 3: results for SHOW PROFILES:

```
+----------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------+---------------+-------------+
| Status               | Duration | CPU_user | CPU_system | Context_voluntary | Context_involuntary | Block_ops_in | Block_ops_out | Messages_sent | Messages_received | Page_faults_major | Page_faults_minor | Swaps | Source_function | Source_file   | Source_line |
+----------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------+---------------+-------------+
| starting             | 0.000081 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | NULL            | NULL          |        NULL |
| checking permissions | 0.000008 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        6043 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000016 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_base.cc   |        4519 |
| After opening tables | 0.000006 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_base.cc   |        4757 |
| System lock          | 0.000006 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | lock.cc       |         308 |
| Table lock           | 0.000007 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | lock.cc       |         313 |
| init                 | 0.000019 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_select.cc |        3427 |
| optimizing           | 0.000015 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_select.cc |        1092 |
| statistics           | 0.000018 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_select.cc |        1373 |
| preparing            | 0.000017 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_select.cc |        1398 |
| executing            | 0.000005 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_select.cc |        2551 |
| Sending data         | 0.121468 | 0.046875 |   0.078125 |              NULL |                NULL |        62672 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_select.cc |        3223 |
| end                  | 0.000017 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_select.cc |        3462 |
| query end            | 0.000010 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        5679 |
| closing tables       | 0.000004 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_base.cc   |         930 |
| Unlocking tables     | 0.000017 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | lock.cc       |         395 |
| freeing items        | 0.000017 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        7331 |
| updating status      | 0.000065 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        1936 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000022 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        1955 |
+----------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------+---------------+-------------+
19 rows in set (0.00 sec)


+----------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------+---------------+-------------+
| Status               | Duration | CPU_user | CPU_system | Context_voluntary | Context_involuntary | Block_ops_in | Block_ops_out | Messages_sent | Messages_received | Page_faults_major | Page_faults_minor | Swaps | Source_function | Source_file   | Source_line |
+----------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------+---------------+-------------+
| starting             | 0.000059 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | NULL            | NULL          |        NULL |
| checking permissions | 0.000007 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        6043 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000020 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_base.cc   |        4519 |
| After opening tables | 0.000006 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_base.cc   |        4757 |
| System lock          | 0.000007 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | lock.cc       |         308 |
| Table lock           | 0.000008 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | lock.cc       |         313 |
| init                 | 0.000020 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_select.cc |        3427 |
| optimizing           | 0.000012 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_select.cc |        1092 |
| statistics           | 0.000013 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_select.cc |        1373 |
| preparing            | 0.000014 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_select.cc |        1398 |
| executing            | 0.000004 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_select.cc |        2551 |
| Sending data         | 0.049592 | 0.062500 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |           43 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_select.cc |        3223 |
| end                  | 0.000017 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_select.cc |        3462 |
| query end            | 0.000005 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        5679 |
| closing tables       | 0.000004 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_base.cc   |         930 |
| Unlocking tables     | 0.000012 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | lock.cc       |         395 |
| freeing items        | 0.000006 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        7331 |
| updating status      | 0.000065 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        1936 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000025 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |            0 |             0 |          NULL |              NULL |                 0 |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        1955 |
+----------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------+---------------+-------------+
19 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT 4: 
The following queries

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT word) from english_british
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT word) from english_american
```

return 111996 and 32197, respectively.

EDIT 5:
It seems that this is not related to the cached results. The speed is the same even when query_cache_size is set to zero.

Comment: Use `set profiling = 1;`  [your_query_1] [your_query_2] then `SHOW PROFILES` you get a list with numbers and used querys use the number of your_query_1 and your_query_2 in this query `SHOW PROFILE ALL FOR QUERY [number]` and post the results here good luck.

Comment: I just posted the results. It seems that "sending data" is the most time-consuming. But what can I do about it?

Comment: Are you using a different search word each time, to be sure that the larger table is not using a cached result?

Comment: It's always the same search word (for testing) for both tables. I just learned about mysql query cache. Is it possible that cache is activated for one table and not for another?

Answer (score 0):

You're right. Use a cluster index for the `word` column and change it to `varchar`. That's because the space required to store a `text` field is more than for storing a `varchar`, so it requires more disk -> memory read. I cannot tell you an exact recipe on why the execution time is that much, but I can advise you to look into execution plans (`EXPLAIN` command) to figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a count(*) and see the number of rows returned from each table.  Maybe the number of rows returned slows it down.

Comment: both queries return just one row

Comment: does it take the same amount of time each time you run it? sometimes when the time is short it flutuates, so you gotta run it many times to see how long it takes on average

Comment: Yes, it fluctuates, but still it's 2.5-3 times slower.

Comment: what about count(distinct word)? from each table? I am just stabbing in the dark here :)

Comment: "1" for both :)

Comment: no i meant do it without the where condition to see how the tables are composed of

Comment: I just posted the results in the original question - EDIT 4